# Can't connect to MongoD / byzarre

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, database

I installed mongoDB through the official tutorial http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+for+Linux

The daemon starts up, a netstat-na | grep 27017 shows:

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:27017 0.0.0.0: * LISTEN
unix 2 [ACC] STREAM LISTENING 100949 / tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

I added these iptables rules:

```
-A INPUT-p tcp-m tcp - dport 27017-j ACCEPT
-A INPUT-p tcp-m tcp - dport 28017-j ACCEPT
```

When loading through the browser, I get well on the web management interface in 28017

If I add a remote connection on mongoHQ, I get to use the database

By cons, if I run the client locally, an error is raised:

```
Error: could not connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell / mongo.js: 79 except: connect failed
```

Same if I try to use the database on an existing project, can't connect to it. 
I turn around, I do not understand, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the mongod process running on the same machine you're connecting from?

Comment: Yes, it running on the same machine

Comment: I have the same problem and the iptables solution didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution if you have this problem :

```
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT  -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
```

And it's ok ^^

Answer (score 0):

Does the firewall need to be explicitly opened on port 27017 to allow outbound TCP connections?

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Same thing, but now have : tcp 0  0 127.0.0.1:27017 127.0.0.1:54581 SYN_RECV when netstat